# Why does Ubuntu Software Center crash on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

when I click to open it, it comes up and then it crashes.

Please help me fix this (also happens with Ubuntu tweak).
I ran the software center from the terminal and got this error:

```
(software-center:18008): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'software-center' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 1523 error_code 9 request_code 62 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Comment: This might be a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1165939).

Comment: I think this is a bug with the version you have, so please report it to **Launchpad** with backtraces attached to it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs As a workaround, you can try to use `synaptic` - which is a preferable way of installing things for many Ubuntu users.